Error while creating managed package -- entities not compatible
I'm creating a managed package and when creating the package I get this error:
Warning: (1) Estas entidades no son compatibles: [Role, Group]
Translation: these entities are not compatible: [Role, Group]
The package.xml contains:
    <types>
        <members>Todos_los_usuarios</members>
        <name>Group</name>
    </types>
...
    <types>
        <members>R2C2_corporativo</members>
        <name>Role</name>
    </types>

The Todos_los_usuarios.group-meta.xml contains:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Group xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <doesIncludeBosses>true</doesIncludeBosses>
    <name>Todos los usuarios</name>
</Group>

The R2C2_corporativo.role-meta.xml contains:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Role xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <caseAccessLevel>Edit</caseAccessLevel>
    <contactAccessLevel>Edit</contactAccessLevel>
    <mayForecastManagerShare>false</mayForecastManagerShare>
    <name>R2C2 corporativo</name>
    <opportunityAccessLevel>Edit</opportunityAccessLevel>
</Role>

I don't know how to solve this error since I don't understand what's wrong...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thx

Both of these Metadata Types are not supported by Managed Packages.
You can check these via the Metadata Coverage Report and search for the metadata type you are looking at.

That's true. I didn't check the metadata coverage report. Thank you Callum!
